# Проблема с YouTube видео

Tags: java, android, youtube-api

Сделал себе ютуб проигрыватель в приложение (по этому уроку https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4hTJybfU7s)
Проблема заключается в том, что когда я переворачиваю в горизонтальное положение приложение, или делаю видео на весь экран, становится просто все черное и перестает работать. Не подскажите что делать в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 0):

**1 ВАРИАНТ**

Вам стоит сохранять состояния. 
Переопределите методы:

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle saveInstanceState);
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle saveInstanceState);
```

Первый метод восстанавливает содержимое из bundle, второй сохраняет (см. https://metanit.com/java/android/12.3.php)

**2 ВАРИАНТ**

Использовать фреймворк MOXY, реализовать паттерн MVP. Отправлять переменные в презентер. (отличная статья https://habr.com/ru/post/276189/)

***Что вам следует почитать:***

1) жизненный цикл активити

2) про все, что выше написал